# What is a flux density of 20 kilolines per $cm^{2}$ in MKS units? What's the origin?

Tags: magnetic-fields, units, history

I just ran across this figure in [MMPA_Magnet_Design_Guide.pdf](http://www.allianceorg.com/pdfs/MMPA_Magnet_Design_Guide.pdf).

I haven't heard of kilolines per $cm^{2}$, so a question of two parts:

1. How to convert kilolines/$cm^{2}$ into MKS units?
2. What is the origin of "lines/$cm^{2}$" as a unit of flux density?

[image: from MMPA_Magnet_Design_Guide.pdf]

Comment: The kiloline is an old cgs unit and is a relic of Faraday counting magnetic field lines.  This link explains a little more. http://www.translatorscafe.com/cafe/EN/units-converter/magnetic-flux/10-7/tesla_meter%C2%B2-kiloline/

Comment: @Farcher - Faraday counted magnetic lines?

Comment: They were called lines of force.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_of_force#Views_of_Faraday

Comment: @Farcher - Envisioned sure, and perhaps counted them in his head at night to sleep. But there wasn't any actual *counting of lines* was there?  Thanks for the table - so it seems `1 line = 1 Maxwell = 1 Gauss cm^2`

Comment: So what is kilolines per square centimetre if it isn't counting lines?

Comment: Aha!  You should ask that question (or search for it) - "What - actually - is a magnetic line of force, and can they be counted?" There are quanta of flux (which are very small), but these lines here we're talking about are abstractions. Macroscopically a field can vary smoothly, it isn't quantized. There can be 17.37284 lines (the unit) of flux. The "s" in lines is confusing because it tends to suggest to us plural, countable. We don't say Teslas or Gausses, but we do say Amps and Volts, but we don't count those either.

Comment: @Farcher - if you want to leave your comment as an answer, I can accept it by the way!

Comment: My question did not require an answer as it was a reflection of a time when theories were not so advanced.  I wonder what those who are living 150 years from now will think of our present efforts.  :-)